# how to make mediaplayer is playing even after exit application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

whenever i click back or click home the sound is stop.. how to make the sound is still playing even when i click home or back button.. sorry for my english.. thank you

here is my main_activity code

```
public class Child extends Activity{

private static final String isPlaying = "Media is Playing";

private MediaPlayer player;
private Button jakartaButton;
private Button acehButton;
private Button jogjaButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.child);

 // Get the button from the view
        jakartaButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.jakarta);
        jakartaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                playSound(1);

            }
         });
        acehButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.aceh);
         acehButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 playSound(2);

             }
         });
         jogjaButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.jogja);
         jogjaButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 playSound(3);

             }
         });
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
    try{
    super.onPause();
    player.pause();
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
 }

 private void playSound(int arg){
    try{
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, " Masuk Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (arg == 1){

        Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying+" jakarta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jakarta);

    }else if (arg == 2){
         Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying+" aceh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.aceh);

     }else if (arg == 3){
         Toast.makeText(this, isPlaying+" jogja", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yogya);
     }
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.start();  
}
```

whenever i click back or click home the sound is stop.. how to make the sound is still playing even when i click home or back button.. sorry for my english..

Comment: read about android's Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Google sample project about playing music across different Android platforms, like Phone, Pad, Watch, Auto... It can keep music playing even app is exited. Take a deep look at [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) , and I think you will be inspired a lot.